# Java Refuses to Start in Linux under low privilege users (works fine as root)

Tags: java, linux, root

I'm stomped.

While as root:

```
root@web01 [~]# uname -a
Linux web01 2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 27 19:49:27 BST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

root@web01 [~]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)
```

While as a low-privilege user:

```
user@web01 [~]# java -Xmx32m -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

**UPDATED:**

Output of ulimit -a (when run as the low privilege user):

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 200000
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) 200000
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7875
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 200000
open files                      (-n) 100
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 35
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 200000
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: What is the output of "ulimit -a"?

Comment: Have you tried running the _same_ command both as root and non-root?

Comment: @Paul Added output of ulimit above.

Comment: @Mat The same command was run, I've posted the one with the memory settings above to show that even when we try to limit it (which is what was recommended in forums) it still doesn't work.

Comment: What distro, and how did you install Java? On my Debian install many of those fields defaulted to `unlimited`.

Comment: CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final) 64-bit. Java was installed by downloading it from the Sun/Oracle website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 200000
```

Here's your culprit. A Java Vm with 32M heap won't fit into that:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.3) (fedora-59.1.10.3.fc15-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
$ ulimit -v 200000
$ java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Comment: This is what we get for the root user:

virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

Why would there be a difference? Where is this configured?

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines to the /etc/security/limits.conf

```
<user> soft as unlimited
<user> hard as unlimited
```

Replace `<user>` with your linux user. -as(address space) will be used to modify virtual/actual memory.